# Pandas - How to compare two consecutive row of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to find percentage difference of two consecutive rows of a column and if the difference is greater than 10 percent I want to return the first value.
For example, In the below data, I want to find percentage difference between df.close[0] and df.close[1] and if the difference is greater than 10 then I want to have value of df.close[0] as df.close[1] if the difference is less than 10 then I want to retain the same values for df.close[0] and df.close[1], how to do it=?

```
           1. open  2. high   3. low  4. close  5. volume
date                                                      
2000-01-03  41.7917  42.5000  40.8333   41.2500  2006460.0
2000-01-04  41.0833  41.0833  38.2500   39.2917  3392856.0
2000-01-05  37.2083  37.2083  34.0000   34.5500  4344624.0
2000-01-06  34.5000  36.3333  34.5000   35.6708  2219904.0
2000-01-07  39.1667  43.2500  38.6667   43.2500  7155936.0
```

I tried the below code, but doesnt seem to work:

```
def percentage_diff(x):
  if (abs((x[0]-x[1]/x[0])*100)>10):
    return x[0]
  else:
    return x[1]

df.close = pd.rolling_apply(df['close'], 2, percentage_diff)
```

Comment: Is this done recursively or as a one-off? For example, if you change `df.close[2]` to `df.close[3]` will this feed your *next* percentage change computation between `df.close[1]` and `df.close[2]`.

Comment: I want to do this recursively, basically there are anomaly values for example [10, 20, 140, 12, 15, 16,...] here, 140 is anomaly. I want to replace 140 with previous value which is 20

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you want to replace the value of `x[0]` with that of `x[1]` for the cases where the percentage difference between the two values `(x[0]-x[1])/x[0])*100` is less than 10%. It is not very clear whether you want to return the x or only an element of x.

```
def percentage_diff(x):
    if (abs((x[0]-x[1])/x[0])*100) > 10:
        return x #or return x[0] if that is what you really want.
    else:
        x[0] = x[1]
        return x #or return x[1] if that is what you really want.
print(percentage_diff([1,1,3,4,54,9])) #the percentage difference between 1 and 1 is less than 10%
print(percentage_diff([1,2,3,4,54,9])) #the percentage difference between 1 and 2 is more than 10%
```

Here is the output for the above code:

```
>>> [1, 1, 3, 4, 54, 9]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 54, 9]
```

And to apply the function to a `pandas DataFrame`, you would do:

```
df['close'] = df.close.apply(percentage_diff)
```

Comment: I want to do this recursively, basically there are anamoly values for example [10, 20, 140, 12, 15, 16,...] here, 140 is anamoly. I want to replace 140 with previous value which is 20

Comment: What is the expected output for the input  [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6] for the function percent_diff?

Comment: its same  [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6]  because the percentage diff between successive values is not more than 10%. But lets say if series was  [1,2,2,3,45,5,5,6]  then percentage diff between 3 and 45 is more than 10, in this case I would expect a series  [1,2,2,3,3,5,5,6]

Comment: Yeh I mean, 45 is clearly an anomaly of value in the above series, hence I want to remove 45 and replace by previous number. What else strategy can we use here?

Comment: Did you also note that the percentage difference between 1 and 2 and 5 and 6 in [1,2,2,3,45,5,5,6] is greater than 10? I think you want to state a numeric difference not a percentage.

Comment: Yes. 45 is clearly an anomaly but by what percentage are you considering the difference in value to be an anomaly? Because if we use 10% the result of  [1,2,2,3,45,5,5,6] should be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186429/discussion-between-nde-samuel-mbah-and-chidu-murthy).

Comment: Ok solved it. Basically function should look like this def percentage_diff(x):
  per = (abs((x[0] - x[1]))/x[1] *100)
  #print('prentage = ', per)
  if (per > 10):
    return min(x[0], x[1])
  else:
    return x[0]. In the above question by returning x[0] or x[1] I was just shifting the anamoly to nex row

Comment: It seems to me that the problem you solved is different than the one in your question?

Answer (score 0):

By using the below function I was able to solve the issue.

```
def percentage_diff(x):
  per = (abs((x[0] - x[1]))/x[1] *100)
  if (per > 30):
    return min(x[0], x[1])
  else:
    return x[0]
```

In my original question, I was returning x[0] or x[1] if percentage diff was greater than 10, this just shifted the value to next row and not really remove the anamoly

```
def percentage_diff(x):
  if (abs((x[0]-x[1]/x[0])*100)>10):
    return x[0]
  else:
    return x[1]

df.close = pd.rolling_apply(df['close'], 2, percentage_diff)
```